# Help with a basic SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I write an SQL query to find out which employees are from a single location where employee and location are different table.

```
select count(*) from employee;
```

The above gives only the count of employees but I need to display their name and location

Comment: Use a join? What's the common column between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT` will obviously give you only the count of the number of employees.

For specific columns such as 'name' and 'location', just do:

```
SELECT e.name, l.location 
FROM employee e
JOIN location l ON e.location_id = l.location_id
```

(or JOIN on whatever is the common association column between the `employee` and `location` table)